# ASP.NET: How to select multiple TreeView nodes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview, treenode

How can I select multiple `TreeNode` objects in a `TreeView` ??

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the DevExpress ASPxTreeView component (part of free ASPxperience Suite) that provides several useful features, such as
Multiple Node Selection
Recursive Node Selection (include three check state)
and others:

[Tree View - Features](http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxperienceDemos/TreeView/Features.aspx)